# Changes in pandas not saving to csv output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a folder CSV files containing lines as follows:

```
Date      | A | B | C |
2021-10-11| A | B | C |
```

I would like to rearrange the date column across every file, for instance, from 2021-10-11 to 10/11/2021.

Currently, my code is pretty simple:

```
import pandas as pd

filenames['A.csv', 'B.csv', 'C.csv']

for filename in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
    df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    df.to_csv('new' + str(filename) + '.csv')
    print(df)
```

However, frustratingly while it does seem to come out correct with 'print(df)' it does not save those changes to the CSV files, apparently. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: what are you opening the CSV files in? Sometimes excel changes the date format itself so whatever format the CSV was created in doesn't matter. Try reading the CSV file using pandas itself and see whether the date format was changed correctly.

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal I'm opening it in Libreoffice, and simply navigating to the file path in a webbrowser, they all still show it as '2021-08-11' for instance.

Comment: Open the "new" files in a text editor to make sure. Sometimes applications change the date format for display purposes